# google action account linking Accounts failed to link

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, actions-on-google

I want to account for linking google action to my web app. followed the OAuth Client Information. I have implemented 
Set Up an OAuth2 Server Using Passport in Laravel( [tutorial link](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setup-oauth2-server-using-passport-in-laravel--cms-30576)).Where I did authentication. finally, I find my application at my home mobile app but when goes to click on MY created app it gives me account linked and after that an error "something went wrong and close" but when I open my
it gives me an error 
[image]  [image]
Accounts failed to link. Please close your browser and try again

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: sir this question is subsequent of this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58197519/the-parameter-state-must-be-set-in-query-string-in-result-what-should-i-do-f

Comment: The more information you can provide in each question, the better our answers can be. What you might see as a subsequent question may not be - so just providing all the information is your best chance of helping us help you.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at [Add authentication to your project](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/develop/create#authentication) indicates that you need to use the *Authorization Code* auth type instead of the *Implicit* flow.

[image]

Comment: yup, I did according to documentation through authorization Code auth,

Comment: but I did not find any clue about when I request to synch it gives me an error " Accounts failed to link. Please close your browser and try again"

Comment: If you didn't find any clue, that is why we're asking you to update your question with as much information as you can provide. Code. Logs. Showing what the URL you received was. Showing what the URL you sent back was. (Masking sensitive information each time.) Right now, you've provided no information to help us help you.

Comment: I am linking my laravel PHP application to google action for that I followed this doc https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2  where I completed the authentication and I am at a level that from my google home mobile app I can open my application authorized and gives message linked and after that gives something went wrong.

Comment: Then please update your question to show as much as you can - don't just mention it in passing in the comments. Show the code. Show any logging you have about what you get (if anything) when you link and when you try to do the sync. Show what you're receiving at each stage. As it stands, you've given us very little information to help us help you.